# Kivy - Drag file on a widget not the window

Tags: python, kivy

I think this question is very basic, but it stops me for two days. 
I want to make a simple Kivy-GUI-App. Drag a folder to a ScrollView, then the ScrollView show the files in the folder. 
Here is where am I:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class DropApp(App):
    def build(self):

        box = BoxLayout()
        scrV = ScrollView(width = 300, height = 400, size_hint_x=None, size_hint_y=None)
        box.add_widget(scrV)

        layout = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None)
        layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))
        for i in range(100):
            btn = Button(text=str(i), size_hint_y=None, height=40)
            layout.add_widget(btn)
        scrV.add_widget(layout)

        Window.bind(on_dropfile=self.handledrops(widget = scrV))

        return box

    def handledrops(self, widget, filename, *args):
        if widget.collide_point(*Window.mouse_pos):
            print(filename)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DropApp().run()
```

NOTE: drop to a widget not the window.
I did a lot of googling, studied a lot of examples. I cannot find what's wrong with the code. 
Most examples on internet use a lot of classes. But what I want is window, button, label.... I try to understand what's class, what's **init**, what's self., what's super(). But they make the code abstract. So I avoid them as possible as i can. Hope someone can help me what's wrong with this code.

Answer (score 0):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class DropApp(App):
    def build(self):

        box = BoxLayout()
        self.scrV = ScrollView(width = 300, height = 400, size_hint_x=None, size_hint_y=None)
        box.add_widget(self.scrV)

        layout = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None)
        layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))
        for i in range(100):
            btn = Button(text=str(i), size_hint_y=None, height=40)
            layout.add_widget(btn)
        self.scrV.add_widget(layout)

        Window.bind(on_dropfile=self.handledrops)

        return box

    def handledrops(self, window_object, filename):
        if self.scrV.collide_point(*Window.mouse_pos):
            print(filename)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DropApp().run()
```

Comment: Hi @Erik ,after change"print(args)" to "print(filename)", your code works on my machine. Thank you very much. I accept this answer. I think the problem is still that I don't have good understanding of Class and Object in Python. Could you explain why you know I need "window_object"? Where to get this kind of knowledge?

Comment: Oops sorry, let me fix that typo, I didn't edit the final code before I pasted. To figure out what was going on, I use `def handledrops(self, *args)` and then I did `print(args)` in the function so I could see what exactly was being passed to the `handledrop` function. It looked like the window object was the first argument and the filename was the second, so I changed `*args` in `handledrops` to be `window_object` and `filename` :)

Comment: Also notice how when you shouldn't use `()` when passing a function to the `on_dropfile` argument. This is because you want to specify the *name* of a function to call when a file is dropped. If you use `()`, it tries to call that function immediately in the `Window.bind(on_dropfile=self.handledrops())`, which is not what you want to do.

Comment: I just try "use def handledrops(self, *args) and then print(args)". The output is (<kivy.core.window.window_sdl2.WindowSDL object at 0x105f1e590>, b'/Users/admin/Desktop/test empty 1'). Very impressive!!!

Comment: Hi @Eric , I have to undo the acceptance. After I change "scrV = ScrollView()" to "scrV = ScrollView(width = 300, height = 400, size_hint_x=None, size_hint_y=None)" The drag and drop doesn't work. Maybe there is other issue need to be solved.

Comment: Works fine for me when specifying a size and position for the scrollview. I edited the code to show it.

Comment: Just have a test. Still no luck on my machine. Upset. my system is Python 3.7; Kivy 1.11.1; MacOS 10.12.6. And  I try change Button to Label, also no luck.

Comment: Did you copy paste the code from my answer exactly?

Comment: Yes. Trust me. with the position and size settings, I do drag and drop more than 50 times, only success 1 time.  But without the settings, success 100%. It looks like the area to accept drop file become very small, and I don't know it's position. I just try change root widget from BoxLayout to FloatLayout, no luck. No any clue, Don't know what to do. Thanks for your time, but I really want to give up this idea.